# Loop does not function properly (python 3.4)

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, python-3.4

I am trying to make a program which can tell if the input license plate is valid or not. 
I want the program to find the index of each characters in the entered input one by one.
I created three functions because the number would mess up the index so each of the functions are intended to go to a certain length then stop.

I also want the program to go into a loop until a certain condition is met. The program does go into loop when this you enter a string that doesn't meet the condition. However, the loop will  break even if you write some of the input characters in lower case.

For example, if i write 'nl03LUD' the program tell me to try again, when i write 'NL03lud' it will not tell me to try again.

Sorry for my bad english, I don't know how to explain it, python visualizer will make my explanation clearer if you don't understand.

Any alterations and feedback would be greatly appreciated

Here is my program:

```
import sys
def lengthchecker(licenseplate):
    length = len(licenseplate)
    if length == 7:
        return('Length of license plate is valid')
    while length is not 7:
        sys.exit('Length of license plate not valid')

licenseplate = str(input('Enter your license plate, do not include space in between, enter in uppercase. \n'))
print(lengthchecker(licenseplate))

def checkletter1(licenseplate):
    x = True
    a = 0
    while 0 <= a <= 1:
        letter = licenseplate[a]
        index = ord(letter)
        if 65 <= index <= 90:
            a = (a + 1)
        else:
            x = False
            return x
    return x

def checkletter2(licenseplate):
    y = True
    b = 2
    while 2 <= b <= 3:
        letter1 = licenseplate[b]
        index1 = ord(letter1)
        if 48 <= index1 <= 57:
            b = (b + 1)
        else:
            y = False
            return y
    return y

def checkletter3(licenseplate):
    z = True
    c = 4
    while 4 <= c <=6:
        letter2 = licenseplate[c]
        index2 = ord(letter2)
        if 65 <= index2 <= 90:
            c = (c + 1)
        else:
            z = False
            return z
    return z

x = checkletter1(licenseplate)
if x is True:
    print('The first two letters you have entered is valid')

while x is False:
    licenseplate = str(input('Enter your license plate again \n'))
    x = checkletter1(licenseplate)

y = checkletter2(licenseplate)
if y is True:
    print('The third to fifth letters you have entered is valid')

while y is False:
    licenseplate = str(input('Enter your license plate again \n'))
    y = checkletter2(licenseplate)

z = checkletter3(licenseplate)
if z is True:
    print('The last three letters you have entered is valid')

while z is False:
    licenseplate = str(input('Enter your license plate again \n'))
    z = checkletter3(licenseplate)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because using `ord` on uppercase letters will return a different value than on lowercase letters. For example:

```
>>> ord('A')
>>> 65
>>> ord('a')
>>> 97
```

Comment: You need to use `str.upper()` on the input. Try adding `.upper()` to the end of your input line.

Answer (score -1):

i've modified your program into more pythonic way:

```
import sys
def length_check(licenseplatenumber):
    if len(licenseplatenumber) != 7:
        print 'The license plate length should be 7'
        return False

    return True

def validate(licenseplatenumber):
    for index,char in enumerate(licenseplatenumber):
        if index == 0 or index == 1 :
            if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90:
                continue
            else :
                print 'Either of first two letters you have entered is NOT valid'
                return False

        if index == 2 or index == 3:
            if 48 <= ord(char) <= 57:
                continue
            else:
                print 'Either of third or fourth letters you have entered is NOT valid'
                return False

        if index == 4 or index == 5 or index == 6 :
            if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90:
                continue
            else:
                print 'Either of last three chars you have entered is NOT valid'
                return False

    return True

while True:
    licenseplatenumber = str(input('Enter your license plate, '
                                   'do not include space in between, enter in uppercase. \n'))
    if length_check(licenseplatenumber):
        if validate(licenseplatenumber):
            print '%s is a valid license plate' %(licenseplatenumber)
            break
```

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: This while loop runs until it broken by 'break'. here, it breaks only for valid license plate.  If you need access to the index as you iterate through the string, use enumerate():                                                                               >>> for i, c in enumerate('test'):  
...     print i, c  
...   
0 t
1 e
2 s
3 t